# paste data at the start of line in visual mode

Tags: vim, vi

I can select lines using `SHIFT + V`, then selecting lines using up down left right keys, then copy them using `y` (yank them) and paste them using `p` (put).

I can similarly select data block using `CTRL + V`, then selecting lines using up down left right keys, then  then copy them using `y` (yank them) and paste them using `p` (put).

But when I am pasting data blocks using `p`, it always pastes data after the current cursor location. Which means, if I want to paste to the beginning of lines, it won't work - it copies the data after the first character. So how can I paste data block at the beginning of a line in vim in visual mode?

Curently I do this by pasting at the second cursor location, deleting the characters at the beginning of line, and then pasting them after the previously pasted block.

Comment: `p` is "put", not "print".

Comment: shift + p puts it before cursor

Comment: [off] OP, where did you got that profile pic? is the same that my muay thai school

Comment: @BetuUuUu From [Deviant Art](http://www.deviantart.com/morelikethis/142653836). Google [tiger on flames](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=muay+thai+school&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=GIuJVPWCMafV8geh7IH4BA#channel=fs&q=tiger+on+flames).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

select and yank as what you are doing, when you paste press `P` instead of `p`. The content in `"` register will be put before your cursor.

also note that: with `p or P`, after your pasting, the cursor will stay at the beginning of the just pasted content. If you want your cursor to be at the end of pasted text, use `gp or gP`.

Answer (score -1):

I think <kbd>I</kbd><kbd>C-r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> could be close to what you want